# Jython Java Package Import Statement

Tags: java, python, memory-leaks, classloader, jython

I wanted to import a java package "`TestPackage`" into jython script,

```
import TestPackage
print TestPackage.SampleClass().getMessage();
```

I am getting the following error,

```
ImportError: No module named TestPackage","errorPoint":"","lineNumber":"1","errorPointMessage":"in <module>\nImportError: No module named TestPackage
```

When I use `from TestPackage import SampleClass` works fine. If I execute `from <pacakage> import <anyclass>` statement once, then `import  <pacakage>` works without the import error.

I tried setting `PySystemState.add_package("TestPackage")`, this works but leading to memory leakage.

Is there any alternative way to make use of `import TestPackage` ? How can I use "`import <packagename>`" in jython without memory leakage?

Comment: What's the full package name of TestPackage? For example, `org.example.test.TestPackage` would be imported as `import org.example.test.TestPackage` or `from org.example.test import TestPackage`. Same as in Java :) If the jar file isn't on your Jython classpath, add it. As a quick hack, `import sys; sys.path.append('/path/to/testpackage.jar')` works.

Comment: It's in the class path with package name as "TestPackage".

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a difference in Java and Python.

In Java you can import classes, and static import constants and static methods. You cannot import a package. `import java.util;` is a compile error, but `import java.util.Collections;` or `import java.util.Collections.*;` are fine. A Java package is a way of organizing a bunch of classes but doesn't isn't a class with a constructor, methods, or constants. I like to think of a Java package as a zip file containing all the classes that belong to that package. A Java package is merely a namespace.

In Python you can import modules, classes, and from-import classes, functions, and constants. However, a Python module is a lot more like a Java class than a Java package. It is not merely a "zip file of classes", but a class that contains subclasses. A Python module is a collection of scripts in a folder with an **init**.py, which defines classes and methods for that module. Thus, you can do things like `import collections`. Python also lets you do `import collections.OrderedDict`, `from collections import OrderedDict`, and `from collections import OrderedDict as OD`.

I hope this explains why you can't import your Java package. You have to import something (probably a class) from that Java package in order for python to create a variable.